# Differentiable Functions on Open Subsets of $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: analysis

Let $U\in\mathbb{R}^m$ open. Show that, in order $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  is differentiable at $a\in U$  is necessary and sufficient that there is, for every $h\in\mathbb{R}^m$ with $a+h\in U$, a linear transformation $A(h):\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(a+h)-f(a)=A(h).h$ and $h \rightarrow A(h)$ is continuous at the point $h=0$. Any ideia?

Comment: Any idea of what?

Comment: Ok, what do you want? Understand the definition of differentiability by means of the introduction of a linear transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of differentiability by means of a linear transformation is different from what is written above. Read calmly.